# How to sort Azure Logs or see recent logs first

Tags: .net, azure, azure-storage

Whenever there is some issue in my Azure portal, I go and check azure trace logs. But logs are displayed in ascending order of timestamp. And I am intersted to see most recent logs first i.e. descending order of timestamp.

Is there way to sort Azure trace logs by TimeStamp descending?

I couldn't find any way. Currently I am filtering logs based on timestamp:

```
Timestamp gt '2011-04-20T00:00'
```

But it will be quite nice to see logs in descending order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there way to sort Azure trace logs by TimeStamp descending?

Directly No. This is because the trace logs data is stored in `WADLogsTable` and Azure Table Service does not support server side sorting. Your best option would be to fetch the data and then sort it on the client side.

Another thing I noticed is that you're querying your table on `Timestamp` attribute. This is a **BIG NO-NO** as data in a table is indexed only on `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` and querying on any attribute other than these two attributes will result in full table scan. You should query on `PartitionKey` value as the `PartitionKey` value in this table actually denotes time in ticks (up to minute's precision). I wrote a blog post about the same some time back which you may find useful: http://gauravmantri.com/2012/02/17/effective-way-of-fetching-diagnostics-data-from-windows-azure-diagnostics-table-hint-use-partitionkey/.

Answer (score 1):

Use Message Analyzer as it now has full log processing and parsing of Azure Storage logs (see [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-e2e-troubleshooting/)) including both server logs, client logs and network logs (http and tcp) plus correlation across the logs.